# Why Jekyll convert my Capital words into lowercase in Categories

Tags: github, jekyll

```
graphics3d
word-cloud
math.se
```

This is my [categories](http://hypergroups.github.io/categories.html)

Why they are all lowercase.

How can I make them into Uppercase, since my directores in my computers are Uppercases.

`![enter image description here][1]`

And my titles: `WordList`, Jekyll will convert it into `Wordlist`.

YML fronter:

```
---
layout: post
category: Mathematica//Math-Experiment
Tags: Formula Periodic Sequence
---
```

https://github.com/HyperGroups/hypergroups.github.com/blob/master/_posts/Mathematica/Math-Experiment/2013-09-11-Math_Experiment_Limit.html

Here you see, I wanna `Mathematica` becomes category not `mathematica`

Comment: @ColeJohnson how about now.

Answer (score 3):

The following is my setup.

```
ruby 2.1.1p76
jekyll 1.0.2
```

I have the same problem, and eventually modified the following source file of jekyll. (I use "rvm")

```
# vim /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-1.0.2/lib/jekyll/post.rb
```

I removed the downcase method.

```
# diff post.rb.org post.rb
79c79
< self.categories = self.data.pluralized_array('category', 'categories').map {|c| c.to_s.downcase}
---
> self.categories = self.data.pluralized_array('category', 'categories').map {|c| c.to_s}
```

Answer (score -1):

making it lowercase makes it easier for Jekyll to parse and handle the project.

I have a couple of questions for you:

1. Is Jekyll's lower-casing of the category names hurting your site performance or causing you any trouble?
2. Or do you want it for the aesthetics only?

If its the latter, the solution is to capitalize it back again.

```
{% for tag in page.categories %}
<a href="{{ site.url }}/categories/index.html#{{ page.categories | cgi_encode }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Other posts from the {{ tag | capitalize }} category" rel="tag">{{ tag | capitalize }}</a>
{% unless forloop.last %}&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: -1. This is not a good (or even complete) solution, because it assumes only first letter is capitalized, which might not be the case (e.g. `jQuery` vs `HTTP` vs `Jekyll`).