# How to Prevent downcase or lowercase conversion of attribute names for a Vue component with Jeykll

Tags: javascript, ruby, vue.js, jekyll

I'm using a Vue component, vue-carousel, in a Jekyll project. Everything is working except the control via attributes because the component is expecting camel case but Jekyll converts attributes to lowercase. So my code:

```
<carousel
  :perPage="1"
  :navigationEnabled="true"
  :navigationNextLabel="'❯'"
  :navigationPrevLabel="'❮'"
  :paginationEnabled="false"
  class="gr__carousel">

  {% for slide in include.content.slides %}
    {% include slide.html %}
  {% endfor %}
</carousel>
```

gets generated with attributes:

```
<div 
  class="VueCarousel gr__carousel" 
  perpage="1" 
  navigationenabled="true" 
  navigationnextlabel="❯" 
  navigationprevlabel="❮">
...
</div>
```

one solution from [Why Jekyll convert my Capital words into lowercase in Categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074064/why-jekyll-convert-my-capital-words-into-lowercase-in-categories)

was to edit the Jekyll gem but I would like to avoid this if possible. Is there any other work around for this situation?

Comment: What happens if you use kebab-case instead?

Comment: that works! I just noticed that Vue hints at this in console with: 'Prop "navigationprevlabel" is passed to component <Anonymous>, but the declared prop name is "navigationPrevLabel". Note that HTML attributes are case-insensitive and camelCased props need to use their kebab-case equivalents when using in-DOM templates. You should probably use "navigation-prev-label" instead of "navigationPrevLabel".'

Comment: Is kebob casing connecting with camelcased properties a functionality of Vue or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue allows the attributes used for passing props to use either camelCase or kebab-case. So if Jekyll is causing problems with `:perPage` you can just use `:per-page` instead.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-name-casing-strongly-recommended

Vue will normalize these prop names when creating the component instances, so they'll always be accessible using camelCase on the instance. So it'll be `this.perPage` no matter how you pass it.

I'm not 100% sure but I think the conversion is done in `normalizeProps`:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/3819af5c9dedde4d1ea81f9caa127e611c8752e3/src/core/util/options.js#L294